# Cannot load a type with JsonProvider

Tags: .net, json, f#, type-providers

I have a sample code snippet where I'm loading a json document but I get this failure at the parsing level :

> The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an error in the context of provided type 'FSharp.Data.JsonProvider, Sample="./SampleModel.json", member 'Parse'. The error: An index satisfaying the predicate was not found in the collection.

The code is quite easy, there's nothing complicated...

```
    type Sample = JsonProvider<"./SampleModel.json"> 
    let jsonFile = "./SampleModel.json"
    let contentList = jsonFile |> File.ReadAllText |> Sample.Parse |> Array.toList

let rec printListContent (list: Sample.Root list) = 
    match list with 
    | [] -> "List is now empty."
    | head :: _ -> sprintf "%s - %s" head.FirstName head.LastName

printListContent contentList
```

Here's the json file:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Baggins",
        "Hobbies": [
            "Mountain Biking",
            "Gaming",
            "Music"
        ]
    }
]
```

Oh by the way, I'm using .NET 4.6 along with F# 4.4.0.0 and FSharp.Data v3.0.0

Comment: I wonder: what happens if you delete the `Id` field from the JSON file? Does the error message change?

Comment: It was exactly that... I'm guessing the provider was expecting another element so it could be indexed properly? @rmunn

Comment: So JsonProvider is doing something special with Ids, presumably trying to match them up across the JSON file so that it can turn things like `UncleId: 3` into a reference like: `FrodoBaggins.Uncle.FirstName = "Bilbo"`. There's probably a way to pass the provider an option to say "Don't convert Id fields for me"; I'll check the documentation.

Comment: Can't find anything in the documentation about this behavior, nor can I easily find where in the source code this is happening. So I don't know how to get you a real answer to your actual problem (which is, presumably, parsing a larger file than the sample file in your question). Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem @rmunn You actually solved my question :-)

Comment: This is really strange - I don't think the provider is doing anything special with IDs (but then, I don't keep track of all new additions, so maybe...). Does it work if you make some other random change in the file? Maybe it was just some weird cache issue...

Comment: @KevinAvignon https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/Lfh807mb/ If you want to display controls under each-other, use flex-direction